# Android Studio C++ <list> begin()/end() no matching function [possible cmake issue]

Tags: c++, android-studio, cmake

I just made a program that compiles and runs perfectly in Visual Studio, and should be compatible with Android (uses no OS-Specific includes), but there is a red error squiggle in Android Studio under the C++ stl list begin and end iterator function (as well as compilation failing as a direct result of it).  I have very little experience with cmake, and being that it is one of the only differences from VS, it seems a likely culprit.

cpp file:

```
void cellStats::removeAllMatches(int row, int col, int val)
{
    std::list<layout>::iterator Layout = layoutListPointer.begin(); // Error here
    while (Layout != layoutListPointer.end()) { // Error here
        if (Layout->get(row, col) != val) {
            layoutListPointer.erase(Layout);
        }
        else {
            Layout++;
        }
    }

    update();
}
```

header file:

```
public:
    void cellStats::removeAllMatches(int row, int col, int val)
    //More
private:
    std::list<layout> layoutListPointer;
    //more
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(${MY_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/cpp)

add_library(native-lib SHARED src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

add_library(cellStats-class SHARED src/main/cpp/cellStats.cpp)
add_library(board-class SHARED src/main/cpp/board.cpp)
add_library(cell-class SHARED src/main/cpp/cell.cpp)
add_library(layout-class SHARED src/main/cpp/layout.cpp)

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
          log-lib

          # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
          # you want CMake to locate.
          log )

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
           native-lib

           # Links the target library to the log library
           # included in the NDK.
           ${log-lib} )
```

Edit: The Error Log is:

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\Metagross\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build C:\Users\Metagross\AndroidStudioProjects\VoltorbFlipCalculator2\app\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\x86 --target cellStats-class}
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cellStats-class.dir/src/main/cpp/cellStats.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\x86\libcellStats-class.so
FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\Metagross\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=i686-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/Metagross/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/Metagross/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/Users/Metagross/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/i686-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11 -std=c++11 -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -nostdlib++ --sysroot C:/Users/Metagross/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-x86 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -LC:/Users/Metagross/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/x86 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libcellStats-class.so -o ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\x86\libcellStats-class.so CMakeFiles/cellStats-class.dir/src/main/cpp/cellStats.cpp.o  -latomic -lm "C:/Users/Metagross/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/x86/libc++_static.a" "C:/Users/Metagross/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/x86/libc++abi.a" && cd ."
C:\Users\Metagross\AndroidStudioProjects\VoltorbFlipCalculator2\app\src\main\cpp/cellStats.cpp:39: error: undefined reference to 'layout::get(int, int)'
C:\Users\Metagross\AndroidStudioProjects\VoltorbFlipCalculator2\app\src\main\cpp/cellStats.cpp:91: error: undefined reference to 'layout::get(int, int)'
C:/Users/Metagross/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/memory:1687: error: undefined reference to 'layout::~layout()'
C:/Users/Metagross/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/memory:1687: error: undefined reference to 'layout::~layout()'
C:/Users/Metagross/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/memory:1687: error: undefined reference to 'layout::~layout()'
C:/Users/Metagross/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/memory:1687: error: undefined reference to 'layout::~layout()'
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Regarding your `CMakeLists.txt` file, are you sure you want to create a total of five shared libraries? Four of which you don't seem to use.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I use all of them, this is just a small segment of my code.

Comment: If you use different libraries for different programs it might make sense, but if you use all of them for a single program, then it doesn't make any sense at all. Then it might not make sense to have any libraries at all, especially shared libraries.

Comment: As for what the problem with the "red squiglies" and the errors during compilation might be, there's really no way to tell since you haven't told us the errors you get! Please copy (as text) the full and complete (including possible informational notes) error output, and then edit your question to paste it (without modifications except formatting). Please see e.g. http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: Okay, you just added the error message, and it should be pretty clear I think. Do the `layout` class have a `get` member function? Since you haven't created a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us only you can tell.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That was the wrong error log.  I attempted to fix it earlier, and forgot to undo all the changes.  I am getting the actual error message now (that I got from the start).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to how you organized your project. You have several small shared libraries that all seems to depend on each other, but you probably don't link with them as needed.

Like the `cellStats-class` library depends on the `layout-class` library (where I assume you define all the `layout` class functions), but you probably don't link with it.

Unless you are going to use all the different libraries separately for different programs, I suggest you don't make libraries at all. Instead add all the sources to the main target you build.

---

On another note, you have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

From [this `std::list::erase` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase):

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated.

That means you can no longer use the iterator `Layout` once you called `erase`. And even if you could you never advance the iterator if the condition `Layout->get(row, col) != val` is true.

You need to use what `erase` *returns*:

```
Layout = layoutListPointer.erase(Layout);
```

Comment: Thanks! I assumed that every class had to be added separately,